# Firestore timestamp with ngx-moment is not working

Tags: angular, typescript, google-cloud-firestore, momentjs, ionic4

I use [ngx-moment](https://github.com/urish/ngx-moment) library. I need to format a datetime like so `Mar 12 at 11 PM`

I have tried like so:

*.html*

```html
<p>{{invitedEvent.startDatetime | amDateFormat: 'MMM DD'}} at {{invitedEvent.startDatetime | amDateFormat: 'hh A'}}</p>
```

But it gives this error:

> Invalid date at Invalid date

Here I use Firestore `timestamp` DateTime like so:

[image]

Above library is working fine if I use like so `<p>{{'24/01/2014' | amParse:'DD/MM/YYYY' | amDateFormat: 'MMM DD'}}</p>`

But what value should I pass here `amParse`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me.

```
 <p>{{invitedEvent.startDatetime.toDate() | amDateFormat: 'MMM DD'}} at
          {{invitedEvent.startDatetime.toDate() | amDateFormat: 'h:mm A'}}</p>
```

**Note:** I have used `.toDate()` and Changed `startDatetime:string` to `startDatetime: Timestamp;`

i.e. `import { Timestamp } from '@firebase/firestore-types';`

Answer (score 0):

Moment works with timestamp and format ISO 8601, change your timestamp format in Firestore.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get you. Can you tell me more?